# getSignedUrl not allowing uploads from browser

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying for a few days to get s3 uploads working directly from the browser.

I am using a jQuery ajax request to query my server for the signed url (to make sure user is authenticated).
I am then returning the signed url and using another jQuery ajax call to try and upload the file.

My backend node.js code:

```
exports.getSignedUrl = async (key, content) => {
  
  try {

    if (!key){
      return Promise.reject('No key supplied');
    }
    if (!content){
      return Promise.reject('No content type supplied');
    }
    
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      region: 'eu-west-1',
      signatureVersion: 'v4'
    });
    let params = {
      Bucket: siteSettings.s3Bucket, 
      Key: key,
      ContentType: content,
      Expires: process.env.S3_UPLOAD_TIME || 240
    };
  
    let url = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
  
    return Promise.resolve(url);

  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

}
```

The `params` variable passed contains:

```
{
    Bucket:"[bucketname]"
    ContentType:"image/jpeg"
    Key:"ctl/5f43d07cbeb97850f4fa5246-small.jpg"
}
```

This produces an URL like:

```
https://[bucketname].s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ctl/5f43d07cbeb97850f4fa5246-small.jpg?Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAXBXXXXXXXXXXBWVG%2F20200923%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200923T101959Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=474415e11b9eec7636ab8a1995a28f92cebab18949fb981d37b6c6772209f039&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
```

My browser code:

```
const getActiveS3SignedUri = (filename, content, callback) => {

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST', 
    url: baseUrl + '/aws/getsignedurl',
    data: {
      filename: filename,
      content: content
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: (data) => {
      if (data.responseJSON && data.responseJSON.success==true){
        callback(null, data.responseJSON);
      } else {
        if (data.responseJSON.err || data.responseJSON.error){
          callback(data.responseJSON.err || data.responseJSON.error);
        } else {
          callback(`Couldn't get URL, unknown error`);
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

const uploadToS3 = (url, fileObject, callback) => {

  let file = document.getElementById(fileObject).files[0];

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST', // I have tried both POST and PUT here
    headers: {"Content-Type": file.type},
    processData: false,
    url: url,
    data: file,
    complete: (data) => {
      callback(null, data);
    }
  })
}

$(() => {

  $('#summernote').summernote({
    callbacks: {
      onImageUpload: function(files) {
        // upload image to S3 server and create imgNode...
        
        $summernote.summernote('insertNode', imgNode);
      }
    }
  });

  $('#validate-target').on('submit', (e) => {

      //- let input = $('#input_dummy');
      //- let val = $('#input_quill > .ql-editor');
      //- input.val(val.html());

  });

  $('#summernote-input').on('change', (e) => {
    let fileInput = $(e.target);
    let file = fileInput[0].files[0];

    getActiveS3SignedUri(file.name, file.type, (err, response) => {
      if (!err){
        uploadToS3(response.url, 'summernote-input', (err, data) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
      }
    })
  });
```

This is posting the following to the AWS url:

```
Host: [bucketname].s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 12147
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:3000/admin/settings/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8
```

With a request payload:

[image: Payload screenshot]

I am constantly getting the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAXBXXXXXXXXXXBWVG</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20200923T102902Z
20200923/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request
9d9d71f4434cbbc236336d33db9e377e2c5790e1acb200e35ece8d25bc96c15b</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>41f375741726f222bcb86018ffae317f9e2a58891105b46783d5f7b343c97352</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>...truncated...</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>POST
/ctl/5f43d07cbeb97850f4fa5246-small.jpg
Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&amp;X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAXBWXRFJB4RKEBWVG%2F20200923%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20200923T102902Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
host:toy-lib-dev-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest><CanonicalRequestBytes>...truncated...</CanonicalRequestBytes><RequestId>470D4BB6D67CDF82</RequestId><HostId>GmktGQDhTmi5a/26bR82tY/SE0C1DQdSZnGNAyp6VGmpYBoTgKXFuTlAYuZpYVCBgdc1Grck6CE=</HostId></Error>
```

My s3 bucket CORS config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I have noticed that the `X-Amz-Date` in the url returned is an hour behind, I assume UTC where I am currently in a BST timezone, could this cause the issue? I have tried setting the expiry to 3700 seconds but this didn't help.

I have tried the following so far to try and get it working:

- Changed between POST and PUT methods
- Removed Expiry timeout
- Removed content-type
- Specified content type as form/multipart
- Tried without specifying region and/or signatureVersion on S3 object
- Changed data sent from just the file to an object `{file: file}`

I've made no progress so far, have i missed something?

**Edit:**

I have tried using `fetch` instead of `$.ajax` and this seems to work without a problem:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: "PUT",
  body: file,
});
```

Comment: I have an example that definitely works: https://github.com/sashee/s3_upload_signed_urls/blob/master/index.html#L28 . It does not match your usecase exactly, but it might be a good starting point

Comment: @TamásSallai Using the browser code from the sample and `fetch` instead of `$.ajax` works, I don't understand why or how though.

Comment: Maybe the content-type header changes the signature. Try removing things from the ajax request and see how it affects the HTTP request sent (you can inspect that in the devtools)

Answer (score 0):

@bendataclear Convert the image file to either blob or base64 string and then deal with it.

Comment: Is that the cause of the signature mismatch? Will supplying a base64 or blob to S3 change how the file is stored?